# Can someone help understand what these different RF power detector specs mean?

Tags: rf, measurement, detection

I've been looking at various RF power detectors for a project I'm working on, but I don't quite understand what the manufacturers mean by "dB range".

For example, the [LT5534](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/5534fc.pdf) Log RF Power Detector has a frequency range of 50 MHz - 3 GHz; the minimum it can detect is -63dB and the maximum is 2 dB. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extract from the LT5534's data sheet. Note the part enclosed in a red box: -

[image]

What that line is saying is that the input power range is -63dBm to -2dBm i.e. a range of 61dB as indicated in the line below.

If you are still confused then 0(zero)dBm is 1 milli watt and if the circuit impedance is 50 ohm this means: -

\$\sqrt{P R}\$ volts or \$\sqrt{1\times 10^{-3}\times 50}\$ volts = 223.6mV RMS.

If you are still confused -63dBm is a power level of 501.2 pico watts and -2dBm is a power of 631 micro watts. I think you should be able to convert these to voltages by now.

Comment: Well explained Andy!!!

Answer (score 1):

The minimum and maximum levels are determined by the linearity and noise floor of the amplifier.  Anything under -63 dBm in this case isn't reliably detectable because the amplifier generates noise on its output that looks like -63 dBm on its input.  Anything over -2 dBm gets clipped or distorted, so it can't be measured reliably.  Say, if you put a -80 dBm signal in, the output will look like you put in a -63 dBm signal.  Or if you put in a +2 dBm signal, the output might say you are putting in a -1 dBm signal.

The frequency range is the range of RF frequencies that it can detect.  Generally there are filters and what not to limit the range of detectable frequencies.  It also depends on the design of the power detector itself.  Anything under 50 MHz or over 3 GHz will either not be detected at all, or they will be detected at a lower sensitivity than signals within the range.  For example, if you put a 4 GHz signal in at -10 dBm, the chip might read it at -20 dBm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I _think_ I'm beginning to understand. One last question though, the maximum output from a UMTS/3G mobile phone (Power class 4), for example, is 21 dBm, does that mean that I can't detect signals from it with the LT5534?

Comment: Are you trying to detect it directly from the output of the chip or with an antenna?  If you have a direct connection, I would recommend a -30 dB directional coupler.  If you are trying to use an antenna, it's unlikely you'll get that much signal as the signal still needs to couple from the phone antenna to your pickup antenna, and the phone likely doesn't transmit at that power very often.  I would suggest adding a switchable 20 or 30 dB attenuator that you can switch in when the signal level is high.

Answer (score 0):

-63 dBm is roughly equivalent to 1 nano Watts
while 
-2 dBm is equivalent to 0.6 milliwatts

All it says is that the device has 61dB (-63dbm minus -2dBm) dynamic range (power range where it will provide linear and correct measurements) and it overloads once you feed it above -2dBm or 0.6 milliwatts.

here is the transfer curve

[image]

Your Vout will register 0.2V if you feed it -60dBm signal bet (50MHz to 3GHz)
while Vout will register near 2.4V(maybe 2.39xxxxxV) if you feed it -2dBm signal bet (50MHz to 3GHz)

Answer (score -1):

It is actually -63dBm  and 2dB , depending on the frequency. It means the range of RF signal to which there is a linearly related output voltage. This detector is equivalent to an anti logarithmic function.